# Read xslt inside jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xslt, jar

```
String fileName = "XSLT/Rules.xsl";
ClassLoader classLoader = new Myclass().getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

In this above code, Eclipse its working fine. But build the jar it's not working. Kindly give the solution.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Could you give some further information on how the code is not working?

Comment: In this error occur during jar file running
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Myclass.main(Myclass.java:14)

Comment: You'll have to indicate exactly where the null pointer exception is, and what it looks like. At the moment nobody reading your question (or comment) can see which part of the code the compiler is breaking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is XSLT/Rules.xsl included in your JAR?  If so, you need to access the file as a resource.  You can get an InputStream with:

```java
InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks @Allen D. Ball. Its very useful.